# Failing to make a grid dynamic via button click [js/css]

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

I'm currently working on the odin project.
Right now I'm on the etch a sketch.
Everything works so far besides creating a dynamic grid.

When you click the button 'Change your grid size' a new grid should appear, in the same space but with more pixels/divs.
What it is doing is, it just adds the divs/pixels to it and the container size also changes.

I've been trying for hours on this.

I assume it is a css problem?

My guess would be that the problem would lay here:

```
    .container>div:nth-child(16n + 1) {
width: 100%;
border: 0;
height: 0;
```

}

Here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/philippgraf11/pen/OJvvopz#

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your script removes only one Child, to empty container you can do instead ` : `cdiv.innerHTML = "";` forked pen https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzaLwaZ

Comment: If I run your codepen I get the same exact result as with mine

Comment: Okay, to me it is different it removes everything before creating a new set of divs. I probably misunderstand your question. What does my fork that it should not ? (is it that rows of 15 divs is not supposed to be 15 anytime, but else ?)

Comment: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BarxKZb ??

Comment: sorry, maybe my wording was a bit wrong. it is supposed to change the number of the divs inside of the grid. so for example u get 100x100 in the same size the first grid was.

Comment: oki, it would be something more alike https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBoYqVP ?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot! you literally made my day, been trying for hours!

Comment: okay, i'll make an answer of it for others

Answer (score 0):

here is an average solution.

it takes the square root and divides width with  it to size children.

```js
const cdiv = document.querySelector(".container");
for (let i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  cdiv.appendChild(div);
  div.setAttribute("class", "farbe");
}
const button = document.querySelector(".neues");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const gridsize = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 255");
  if (gridsize != null) {
    cdiv.innerHTML = "";                                       // empty the grid

    if (gridsize > 0 && gridsize < 255) {                      // get user input and add divs
      let size = (600 / Math.round(Math.sqrt(gridsize)));      //use square root to calculate children's size
      if (gridsize < 3) {
        size = size / 2;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < gridsize; i++) {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        cdiv.appendChild(div);
        div.setAttribute("style", "width:" + size + "px;height:" + size + "px;");// update size
      }
    } else {
      alert("Please enter a number between 1 and 255");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 75px;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 610px;
  margin: auto;
  counter-reset: divs;
}

.container>div::before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
  margin: auto;
}

.container>div {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transition: ease 99999999999999999s all;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
}

.farbe:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: ease 0s all;
}

.farbe {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.neues {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: medium;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hintergrund {
  background-color: grey;
}

.ueberschrift {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body class="hintergrund">
  <h1 class="ueberschrift">Sketchpad </h1>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <button class="neues"> Change your grid size!</button>
</body>
```